# auto-scale policy kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

Estoy tratando de hacer un `yaml` con una `policy` de `auto-scaling` de esta forma:

```
Scale in: CPU utilization > 40%
Scale out: CPU utilization < 20%
```

Pero no tengo idea de cómo poder poner ambas condiciones ya que según veo solo puedo aplicar una sola condición, pero no ambas a la vez. ¿Hay alguna manera de expresar esto en el `yaml` del `hpa` que intento hacer?

La base del `yaml` seria así:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: apache-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: apache-deployment
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 20
```